# Spring Google Sign On and Basic Auth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, google-oauth

I have a spring boot application and have a mobile app (react-native) which consumes this app.
I build my whole security system for authenticating with basic authentication mechanism in spring boot.The users have to sign up through a form in application but in order to feedbacks i take users are looking for a simple sign on button mostly like google or facebook etc. 
The thing is whole http requests from app includes a "Autherization : Basic " header as it should be in my case.I wonder if i can implement Google simple sign on mechanism into an app like that ?
Question one : İf yes , how should i handle the making http requests with google signed in user and basic authentication users.What should be the logic for front-end ? 
Question two : In server side , how should i handle the google signed on requests and basic auth requests on same urls ? As user activities wont differ in app , the end points wont differ too.Should i make different endpoints which calls the same business logic as if they were basic auth urls for google sso urls too ?

Comment: Did you build the current auth yourself or with spring security?

Comment: I used BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint class with HttpSecurity.httpBasic() configuration in my WebSecurityConfig class.So i guess your questions answer is spring security.